# How to convert Grayscale/binary Mat to QImage?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing

I have started learning Qt and is trying to make a simple video Player which will load the video and will play it. It worked perfectly fine. Now added thresholding functionality to it. The threshold value will be obtained from the spinBox.
Code is written in such a way that thresholding operation will be done with value in spinBox except at value 0 (where normal video is displayed).
So this is my function for the same:

```
void Player::run()
{

while(!stop )
{

    if(!capture.read(frame))
        stop = true;
    // convert RGB to gray
    if(frame.channels() == 3)
    {
        if(thresh == 0)
         {
            cvtColor(frame, RGBframe, CV_BGR2RGB);
            img = QImage((const unsigned char*)(RGBframe.data),
                          RGBframe.cols,RGBframe.rows,QImage::Format_RGB888);

         }
        else
        {
            Mat temp;
            cvtColor(frame, temp, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            threshold(temp, binary, thresh, 255, 0);
            img = QImage((const unsigned char*)(binary.data),
                              binary.cols, binary.rows, QImage::Format_Indexed8);




            bool save = img.save("/home/user/binary.png");

             cout<<"threshold value = "<<thresh<<endl;

            //imshow("Binary", binary);
        }
     }
     else
     {
        if(thresh == 0) // original Image
        {
            img = QImage((const unsigned char*)(frame.data),
                             frame.cols,frame.rows,QImage::Format_Indexed8);

        }
        else // convert to Binary Image
        {

            threshold(frame, binary, thresh, 255, 0);

            img = QImage((const unsigned char*)(binary.data),
                              binary.cols, binary.rows, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
        }




     }

     emit processedImage(img);
     this->msleep(delay);
}
}
```

for spinBox value equals 0 it runs fine but when spinBox value is incremented I get only black screen. I tried `imshow(cv:: Mat binary)`and it is showing the correct binary image but when I try to save `QImage img` it is some random black and white pixels (though of same size of original frame).

Comment: It seems that you're missing a colorTable. Add this before the while loop: `QVector<QRgb>  sColorTable(256); for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i){sColorTable[i] = qRgb(i, i, i);}`, and after you create the `QImage` from binary, add `img.setColorTable(sColorTable);`

Comment: the color image input case or the grayscale image input case? afair grayscale isn't indexed8 type in Qt, afair i had to use a color table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're missing the color table for your indexed image. You need to add a color table (before the while loop):

```
 QVector<QRgb> sColorTable(256); 
 for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i){ sColorTable[i] = qRgb(i, i, i); }
```

and after you create the `QImage` from the binary `Mat` you need to add

```
 img.setColorTable(sColorTable);
```

Or, as pointed out by [@KubaOber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742197/how-to-convert-grayscale-binary-mat-to-qimage/40742436?noredirect=1#comment68729658_40742436), from Qt 5.5 you can also use the format `QImage::Format_Grayscale8`:

```
// From Qt 5.5
QImage image(inMat.data, inMat.cols, inMat.rows, 
             static_cast<int>(inMat.step),
             QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
```

In general, you can wrap all `Mat` to `QImage` conversion in a function. Below there is the *bug corrected* and *updated* version of `cvMatToQImage` originally found [here](https://asmaloney.com/2013/11/code/converting-between-cvmat-and-qimage-or-qpixmap/).

You can then remove all the conversion to `QImage` from your code and use this function instead.

```
QImage cvMatToQImage(const cv::Mat &inMat)
{
    switch (inMat.type())
    {
        // 8-bit, 4 channel
    case CV_8UC4:
    {
        QImage image(inMat.data,
            inMat.cols, inMat.rows,
            static_cast<int>(inMat.step),
            QImage::Format_ARGB32);

        return image;
    }

    // 8-bit, 3 channel
    case CV_8UC3:
    {
        QImage image(inMat.data,
            inMat.cols, inMat.rows,
            static_cast<int>(inMat.step),
            QImage::Format_RGB888);

        return image.rgbSwapped();
    }

    // 8-bit, 1 channel
    case CV_8UC1:
    {
#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050500

        // From Qt 5.5
        QImage image(inMat.data, inMat.cols, inMat.rows, 
                     static_cast<int>(inMat.step),
                     QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
#else
        static QVector<QRgb>  sColorTable;

        // only create our color table the first time
        if (sColorTable.isEmpty())
        {
            sColorTable.resize(256);
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
            {
                sColorTable[i] = qRgb(i, i, i);
            }
        }

        QImage image(inMat.data,
            inMat.cols, inMat.rows,
            static_cast<int>(inMat.step),
            QImage::Format_Indexed8);

        image.setColorTable(sColorTable);
#endif
    }

    default:
        qWarning() << "cvMatToQImage() - cv::Mat image type not handled in switch:" << inMat.type();
        break;
    }

    return QImage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this additional function @Miki

Comment: For grayscale images we also need a colorMap right?

Comment: **Only** for grayscale images

Comment: Remember that binary images are just grayscale images with two values only, 0 and 255 (at least in OpenCV implementation. The type is always CV_8UC1)

Comment: For grayscale, on Qt>=5.5 you can use `QImage::Format_Grayscale8` instead of an indexed format.

Comment: @Optimus1072 Please check updated answer. You can use `QImage::Format_Grayscale8` and avoid the color table.